# What's the meaning of b[a[i] - 1]++?

Tags: java

I just found a piece of code that i don't understand.

```
b[a[i] - 1]++;
```

this is the context.

```
int firstDuplicate(int[] a) {
        int[] b = new int[a.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            b[a[i] - 1]++;            
            if (b[a[i] - 1] > 1) {
                return a[i];
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

The array is

```
int test[] = {2, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2};
```

Can please someone explain it to me?

Comment: `b[a[i] - 1]++` means `b` array at index `a[i] - 1` is now `+= 1`

Comment: It's just an array indexed by an expression other than a literal or a variable like you may be used to seeing.

Comment: Increment the element of `b` indexed by the element of `a` at `i` minus one.

Comment: do you understand what this function is trying to achieve?

Comment: Well i guess i do understand, but please if you can explain it to me, is best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a[]` is an array of Integers.

`b[a[i]]` means in array `b` at index `a[i]`.

e.g.

```
a[] = {1, 2, 3} & b[] = {10, 20, 30}
```

Here, `b[a[0]]` will give you `20` because `a[0]` returns `1` and `b[1]` is `20`.

In your code it is `b[a[i] - 1]++` which is equivalent to `b[a[i] - 1] = b[a[i] - 1] + 1`

Taking from my e.g. if `i = 0`

`b[a[0] - 1]` will give you `10` as output.

And moreover `b[a[0] - 1]++` will modify the value at `b[0]` to `11`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I think i got it.

Answer (score 0):

The array "a" must contain positive integers, no smaller than 1, and no greater than "a.length".

This code creates an array "b" to track how many of each integer has been seen.

So for example b[0] represents the number of 1's, b[1] represents the number of 2's, and so on.

By performing b[...]++ you are incrementing the count at that position.